# How to print the result of caml query?

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml

I've got a list with 2 columns col1 and col2. I wrote a CAML query and I want to print the value from the second column corresponding to the value from the first

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(administrationUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["list"];

        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = "<Where>" +
                        "<Eq>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='col1'>" + "<Value Type='Text'>Test</Value>" +
                        "</Eq>" +
                      "</Where>";
        SPListItemCollection collection = list.GetItems(query);
        foreach (SPListItem item in collection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item["col2"]);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you create columns "col1" and "col2", the columns internal names will "_x0063_ol1" and "_x0063_ol2".

Modify the code as below:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(administrationUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["list"];

        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = "<Where>" +
                        "<Eq>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='_x0063_ol1'/>" + "<Value Type='Text'>Test</Value>" +
                        "</Eq>" +
                      "</Where>";
        SPListItemCollection collection = list.GetItems(query);
        foreach (SPListItem item in collection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item["_x0063_ol2"]);
        }
    }
}
```

If you use SharePoint Online, we need use CSOM code to achieve it.

```
string siteUrl = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/lz";
var login = "lz@test.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "xx";

ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);


List oList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("list");

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='_x0063_ol1'/><Value Type='Text'>test</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";

ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
ctx.Load(collListItem);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
{
    Console.WriteLine(oListItem["_x0063_ol2"]);
}
```